# Prevent webpage access unless checkout is successful

Tags: paypal, download

I have a digital download page. The page is loaded on successful PayPal payment. Can I prevent direct user access to the download page if the user simply types the URL in their browser address bar?

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is similar to showing pages to a user if he is authenticated. The implementation details will depend on the tech that you are using. For something like showing download page for successful payment, let's assume that you have an order and assume it tracks whether payment was successful (maybe as a boolean) .e.g. id: 1234, paymentSuccessful: false. What you can do, at the router, when a request to view `order/1234/download` is done, check if the paymentSuccessful is true. I hope this gives you an idea of how to go about it.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Do I set a advanced variable from the PayPal button creation page that I can use on successful payment? Will this variable be available for me to use on the page PayPal redirects to after payment?